# jquery remove tags from external files and save them

Tags: jquery, xml, tags

Greetings,

I need to remove  tags (about 1000) within an XML file. I tried it with jquery, but with no success:

```
<html>
<!--jquery app removes specific <t2_patch ...>-tag -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Kill t2_patch-tags </button>
<script>
        $("button").click(function () {
    $('/home/dan/series14AreaListOnly.xml').remove('t2_patch');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My aim is to remove t_patch -tags within an 300MB large XML file. Is this approach I did so far ok, or am I completely wrong. How can I save the changes ? (Because the remove() function actually does not remove anything directly on the xml file ?).

Thanks in advance for any hints and with best regards

Daniyal

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to set up a backend php script and ping it what entities to remove and wait for a callback, much faster and reliable, less hackable because what if someone does:

```
 $('/home/dan/series14AreaListOnly.xml').remove('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't XSLT? And, what is the meaning of remove **tags** in XML?

If you mean to strip of the element, this stylesheet removes any `t2_patch` element in input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="t2_patch"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you mean to strip of the element but keeping its content, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="t2_patch">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: Overwriting the identity rule.